# Problem with a front end of compressed files

Tags: bash, tar, compression, gzip, bzip2

I need to make a frontend for compressed files, the idea is that if you receive a gz or bz2 file, uncompress it with gunzip and bunzip2.

If what you receive is a tar.gz or a tar.b2 you should unpack and unzip it once with tar xzf or xjf.
My code is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -ne 1
then
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 archivo"
    exit 1;
fi

case "$1" in
    *.gz)
        echo "gzip"
        echo "Descomprimiendo"
        `gunzip $1`
    ;;
    *.bz2)
        echo "bzip2"
        echo "Descomprimiendo"
        `bunzip2 $1`
    ;;
    *.tar.gz)
        `tar xzvf $1`
    ;;
    *.bzip2.gz)
        `tar xjvf $1`
    ;;
esac
```

The problem is that even if I pass a file with extension .tar.gz I enter the first condition of the case, I have tried to add the dollar to be strictly that it ends like that but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change order of case code blocks and add a break after each one.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -ne 1
then
    echo "Numero de parametros incorrecto"
    echo "Uso del programa: $0 archivo"
    exit 1;
fi

case "$1" in
    *.tar.gz)
        tar xzvf "$1"
        break
    ;;
    *.bzip2.gz)
        tar xjvf "$1"
        break
    ;;
    *.gz)
        echo "gzip"
        echo "Descomprimiendo"
        gunzip "$1"
        break
    ;;
    *.bz2)
        echo "bzip2"
        echo "Descomprimiendo"
        bunzip2 "$1"
        break
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown extension"
        break
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think there are error at `*.bzip2.gz`, should be `*.tar.bz2`, but you known what files you have better then me.